# 'Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel' does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Tags: c#, powershell, asp.net-core

I'm trying to run the latest [Asp.Net 5 samples](https://github.com/aspnet/Home) (currently 1.0.0-rc1-update1) from powershell on Windows 10. I have the active and default DNX set as the CLR x86. I have run the `dnu restore` command against each of the 3 projects and this has completed without error.

If I run the command `dnx run` for the console sample this works fine. However, when I then run the command `dnx web` from within either of the web project's folders I get the error message;

`'Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel' does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point`

The samples are pretty basic and so I assume it must be part of my dnx configuration. But why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure you're targeting **DNX** 1.0.0-rc1-update too? Looks like you're on rc2. Try running `dnvm upgrade`.

Comment: Nope definitely RC1. RC2 isn't released till Feb ...

Comment: Yes, but did you downloaded and use it by accident? What does `dnvm list` shows?

Comment: Like I said, it's not installed. I'm not even sure RC2 exists yet.

Comment: I see that you found the issue. But, there are nightly builds of RC2 available on the MyGet feeds, when you run `dnvm upgrade -u` it will install the latest RC2 build. Asked it because RC2 has a lot of changes regarding this.

Comment: I've got this error on xubuntu 14.04 with coreclr rc1-update1. Updated to rc2, no change. Mono not installed, so can't downgrade that... I'm trying to run HelloMVC from git aspnet samples, todays latest.

Comment: I had the same problem. I was trying to run examples from 'latest' folder and I had the same error. I changed folder to 1.0.0-rc1-final and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the issue is a strange one actually but it looks like the `dnu restore` command is case-sensitive. I assume this has something to do with it having to run on Linux too but I'm not sure.

In powershell my current path was all lowercase but my folder structure wasn't. Whilst in `webhello` , if I ran the command `cd ..\WebHello` and then ran `dnu restore`, the restore worked fine and the `dnx web` command also then ran fine.

Interestingly, if I ran `cd ..\webhello`, the `dnx web` command still works fine.