# Project 'Unable to locate Dependency' on itself

Tags: asp.net, ubuntu, asp.net-core

I'm trying to run the latest [Asp.Net 5 samples](https://github.com/aspnet/Home) (currently 1.0.0-rc1-update1) on my Ubuntu 14.04 VM guest using VirtualBox on Windows 10. The sample code is being run via shared host directory.

I have the active and default DNX set as the CoreCLR x64.

When I have run the `dnu restore` command against either of the 2 web projects, the restore completes but with an error message. For example, for the HelloWeb project:

`Unable to locate Dependency helloweb >= 1.0.0`

If I run then command `dnx web` for the web projects I get the error message:

`Error: Unable to load application or execute command 'Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel'. Available commands: web.`

I have a [related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34676489/microsoft-aspnet-server-kestrel-does-not-contain-a-static-main-method-suitab) as I am also trying to also get the same samples running on my Windows machine. As they are basic and also unmodified, so I can't understand why they are not working. To make things worse, I actually had them running on this VM yesterday in the same manner I am trying here and as far as I'm aware, nothing has changed other than I have restarted the VM in the meantime.

Can anyone suggest why the projects are referencing themselves in this way and how I can resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was being caused because the source code was being shared and the project.lock.json file had been created by the `dnu restore` process on Windows. I created a separate set of code samples and the code restored then ran fine.

This doesn't explain why the message was appearing but I assume the message `Unable to locate Dependency helloweb >= 1.0.0` is actually a red herring and possibly refers to the fact that it can't replace the lock file.